# Custom background for UINavigationBar in landscape mode

Tags: iphone, uinavigationbar

I am adding a custom background for my UINavigationBar. It works fine as long as the phone is in portrait mode. As soon as I switch to landscape mode, half the bar appears blue (the default navbar color) and half of it has my image

How can I stretch the image for landscape mode and make it small again for portrait mode?

Thanks

***Solution***
Incase anyone is looking for an answer to how to add an image to navigation bar - here goes

```
UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 480.0, 44.0)];
[imgView setImage:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"navbar_landscape" ofType:@"png"]]];
[navigationController.navigationBar addSubview:imgView];
[imgView release];
```

Comment: I had to change that second line to: 
[imgView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"navbar.png"]];
...in case anyone struggles with noshow.

Comment: Thanks, uhm the post is a bit old, anyway.. what about changing the height of the navigationBar ? Should I subclass it in that case ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably need to set the autoresizingMask of your background image view; try using `UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight`

Answer (score 6):

In both screen orientation modes it's much better to use

```
[navigationController.navigationBar insertSubview:imgView atIndex:0];
```

This puts image view under all other views and all the default navigation bar elements (title, standard buttons) work OK.

Answer (score 6):

After a bit of research and trail and error, I found a work around, that will not replace the navbar when you enter the movie playback mode. Hopeefully this does not cause problems with app approval, but based on this post, I think it should be fine:

http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/qa/qa2009/qa1637.html

```
@implementation UINavigationBar (UINavigationBarCategory)

- (void)drawLayer:(CALayer *)layer inContext:(CGContextRef)ctx
{
    if([self isMemberOfClass: [UINavigationBar class]]){
        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"navBarBackground.png"];
        CGContextClip(ctx);
        CGContextTranslateCTM(ctx, 0, image.size.height);
        CGContextScaleCTM(ctx, 1.0, -1.0);
        CGContextDrawImage(ctx, CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height), image.CGImage);
    }else{
        [super drawLayer:layer inContext:ctx];
    }
}

@end
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution Ben gave did solve the problem but it stretches the image in landscape mode. I ended up creating two images- one for landscape and other for the portrait mode. I then added code in shouldAutoRotate to change the navbar image based on the orientation

Answer (score 1):

You can change the image for both portrait and landscape orientations by supplying different images for different orientations by checking the frame size of that UINavigation bar instance:

```
- (void) drawLayer:(CALayer *)layer inContext:(CGContextRef)context
{
    if ([self isMemberOfClass:[UINavigationBar class]] == NO) {
        return;
    }

    UIImage *image = (self.frame.size.width > 320) ?
                        [UINavigationBar bgImageLandscape] : [UINavigationBar bgImagePortrait];
    CGContextClip(context);
    CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0, image.size.height);
    CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1.0, -1.0);
    CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height), image.CGImage);
}
```

And [this complete demo Xcode project](http://www.ardalahmet.com/2011/02/11/ios-development/customizing-the-appearance-of-uinavigationbar/) on customizing the appearance of UINavigationBar might be helpful. It also includes @2x versions of background images to support retina displays on iPhone 4 devices.

Comment: This is _by far_ the best, most comprehensive solution I've seen and your example project in github is excellent. **Thank you.**  I would encourage everyone to vote this up.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'm glad you find it useful.

Answer (score 0):

Try the simpler method of `[UIImage imageNamed:@"navbar_landscape.png"]` since a UI element is exactly what **imageNamed:** is intended for, as ljonesATL shows.