# Set Height of UINavigationBar

Tags: ios, ipad, uinavigationbar

If you take a look at the Prezi iPad App, their navBar is bigger than the standard one. Does anyone know how to accomplish that?

Thanks in advance

Comment: This should help you: [Change the height of NavigationBar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8285728/change-the-height-of-navigationbar-and-uibarbuttonitem-elements-inside-it-in-coc)

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of the Prezi iPad app?

Comment: http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/prezi-viewer/id407759942?mt=8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to subclass the UINavigationBar:

```
@interface MyNavigationBar : UINavigationBar

@end

@implementation MyNavigationBar

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
  [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 65)];
}

@end
```

Then you need to create a Category for the UINavigationBar to use the subclass:

```
@implementation UINavigationBar (CustomImage)

//for iOS 5 
+ (Class)class {
  return NSClassFromString(@"MyNavigationBar");
}

- (void)layoutSubviews {
  [super layoutSubviews];
  self.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 65);
}

@end
```

Comment: You can subclass a UINavigationController and then put that code on the .m file of your subclass.

Comment: How would that look like in Swift?