# Custom navigation bar

Tags: iphone, ios, user-interface, uinavigationcontroller, navigationcontroller

I was crawling Dribble and found the attached design. I was wondering how to do a custom navigation bar like this. I mean how create the navigation bar once and reuse it implicitly for every view controllers.

I was thinking about having a kind of root view controller and inherit for other view controllers, but I don't know how to do this.

Any idea or link will be appreachated!

Cheers.

Cyril

[image: Nav bar image]

Comment: I would also like to see how it's done!

Comment: This is exactly what i require in my current project

Answer (score 8):

Thanks to iOS5 you are now able to customise the appearance of a UINavigationBar without having to subclass or create a category.

The following code block (put it in your applicationDidFinishLoading: method) will change the UINavigationBar for the whole application to whatever image you give it.

*Note, this will ONLY work in iOS5*

`[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"nav bar.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];`

However, you are also able to change the appearance of a single UINavigationBar depending on what view controller you're in by using the following code in viewDidLoad.

`[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"nav bar.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];`

*The above code is solely discussing the new ways to customise the UINavigationBar appearance thanks to iOS5. However, it does not discuss the way that the buttons have been implemented.*

However, adding the buttons is a different game altogether. For this, I would recommend subclassing `UINavigationBar`, and then adding in the buttons where needed through that. You could probably even get away with just a standard `UINavigationBar` but custom `UIBarButtonItem`s that run off a particular view.

For example:

```
UIView *rightButton = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 30.0f, 30.0f)] autorelease];
[rightButton addSubview:[UIImage imageNamed:@"rightButtonImage.png"]];

UIBarButtonItem *rightButtonItem = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:rightButton] autorelease];
[rightButtonItem setAction:@selector(rightButtonAction:)];
```

I haven't tested that code so it isn't a copy/paste solution, but it gives you an idea of what needs to be done to accomplish "custom" looking UIBarButtonItems.

Good luck!

Answer (score 6):

In older iOS versions you have to subclass UINavigationBar i.e.:

```
@interface CustomNavigationBar : UINavigationBar
@end

@implementation CustomNavigationBar

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if (self) {
        self.opaque = YES;
        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"CustomBackground"]];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    // Skip standard bar drawing
}

@end
```

To use a custom navigation bar in your view controller, you should change a standard class name to `CustomNavigationBar` in XIB.

Also, you can set the custom navigation bar programmatically:

```
UIViewController *tempController = [[[UIViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
UINavigationController *navigationController = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:tempController] autorelease];

NSData *archive = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:navigationController];
NSKeyedUnarchiver *unarchiver = [[[NSKeyedUnarchiver alloc] initForReadingWithData:archive] autorelease];
[unarchiver setClass:[CustomNavigationBar class] forClassName:@"UINavigationBar"];
UINavigationController *customNavigationController = [unarchiver decodeObjectForKey:@"root"];

UIViewController *contentController = [[[ContentViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
customNavigationController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObject:contentController];
```

Now `customNavigationController` has the custom navigation bar.

Answer (score 3):

set a custom background for the NavigationBar

```
UIImage *navBackground =[[UIImage imageNamed:@"navbarBackground"] 
                 resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)];
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:navBackground forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

then in your View Controller set custom views for left, rightBarButtons and title.

```
self.navigationItem.titleView = customTitleView;
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = customBarButton;
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = customBarButton2;
```

Comment: I have another question @eric-lars0n. How would I actually make the navigation buttons like in the picture? Do I have to specify a UI frame the size of the square of the button, and add it as a subview for the nav bar?

Answer (score 1):

You would need to make your own `UINavigationBar` subclass, and use in places where you would need a navigationController.

In this custom class is where you will draw the background, buttons, text, etc.

---

### Update

Actually, taking a closer look at this example, it appears to be a `UIToolBar`. You can assign navigation methods to the buttons like `popViewController:` etc. For the "Confirm Information" and progress indicator, you can use a label and an image. For the right button, its just a graphic.

Of course, the example you provided is simply a concept, and not an actual app. But with some creativity, a few hours of coding and a few more hours of graphics design, you can achieve this same interface.

Comment: In fact, this motivates me to write a custom navigation controller. If I get something up and running, I will post it to github and update with a link.

Comment: UINavigationController class reference: "This class is not intended for subclassing." However, you may find my post in the following question to be of help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6398869/how-to-assign-my-customnavigationbar-to-a-uinavigationcontroller

Comment: UINavigationBar subclassing, not controller.

Comment: Interesting, I really need to see your implementation to understand how it works :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the stock UINavigationController and hide the UINavigationBar.

Then, make your own subclass of UIViewController which has all of the navigation elements, and then a flexing size view where the contents go.  Make all of your classes subclass this element and draw into the view.  The button simply has to call `[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES]` and the UILabel at view just has to set its text to `self.title`.

Comment: I was thinking about a solution based on this, creating a custom root view controller managing a custom navbar and animations, but I don't know how to use it with inheritance, any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Using `Category`, add code below in your delegate file (.m)

```
@implementation UINavigationBar (UINavigationBarCategory)

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    UIImage *navBg = [UIImage imageNamed:@"NavBar.png"];
    [navBg drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)];
}
@end
```

Edit:

Using `Category` is not a good way, I wrote a demo without using `Category`, click [here](https://github.com/looyao/CustomNavigationBar).

Comment: Apple engineers advise to never ever use a category to customize navigation bar appearance.

Comment: @SteveCotner see my edit, I wrote a demo to customize navigation bar. In iOS5 or above, using category drawrect can't change the navigation bar apperence, and if you use like MFMailComposeViewController, its apperence looks ugly.

Comment: Thanks. In iOS 5 (and 6... shh...), I made a category and overrode sizeThatFits: to change the appearance. Hacky, I know, as it's sometimes called more than once on a single view. But it has worked so far and kept me from having to customize it in every view controller. Apple wouldn't reject an app for doing that, would it?